# Laravel 5 DOMPDF - Class Font_Metrics not found

Tags: php, laravel-5, dompdf

I want to generate PDF files from Laravel views with UTF-8 special characters using barryvdh/laravel-dompdf, but the included fonts are not supporting this. So I tried installing new fonts using load_font.php, but it says:

> Fatal error: Class 'Font_Metrics' not found in /vendor/dompdf/dompdf/font_load.php on line 67

How do I fix this?

Comment: Not an solution for this specific problem, but have you tried using the included Deja Vu fonts?

Comment: I think maybe a few more details would help. How are you running load_font.php? When running that script dompdf_config.inc.php should be run which will then run the dompdf autoloader. Unless the autoloader is disabled in your configuration (see `DOMPDF_ENABLE_AUTOLOAD`).